# Marking a slide with blue circle on top right hand side of given beamer slides?

Tags: beamer

I would like to mark some given slides with a 1cm about or more blue colored circle. Herewith it will show which slides might be more important.

Which possible method that won't interfer with frame and the slide figure position? Ideally would be on top layer, without shifting down the figures of the beamer slide.

Thank you in advance !!
Yours Sincerely

```
\documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}


\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\thesection.~\insertsection}
\begin{itemize}
\item Header
\begin{itemize}
\item Example
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\thesection.~\insertsection}
\begin{itemize}
\item Header
\begin{itemize}
\item Example
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\clearpage
\begin{frame}
\vspace{3.3cm}
\begin{center}
{\fontsize{30}{40}\selectfont {\it Thank you for your attention}}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE does not compile :(

Answer (score 1):

Quick hack: misuse the logo layer

```
\documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\logo{\Huge\textcolor{structure.fg}{\textbullet}\vspace{8.6cm}}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\thesection.~\insertsection}
\begin{itemize}
\item Header
\begin{itemize}
\item Example
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the problem is if I use Madrid or California theme (red one color) and a top banner, the logo (blue) is under the header. Would you have a solution to bring the logo (blue color) on the top layer?

Comment: @linux786 For Madrid theme, you could add the circles to the frametitle. E.g. `\frametitle{\thesection.~\insertsection\hspace{9cm}\Huge\textcolor{red}{\textbullet}}`. I don't know of a `California` theme

Comment: I would like to keep the frametitle unchanged, otherwise it will make it too complicated. Is it simply possible that your solution is updated that it goes on the top layer? thank you in advance

Comment: The frametitle hack is unstable, and it does not work. I tried again and the logo solution does not work. Nothing work. What about hbox use? Cannot we force latex to write on top layer somehow?

Comment: what about the use of textblock for x and y placement? or maybe: \begin{picture}(50,50)
\put(200,-300){\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{file}}}
\end{picture} ?

Comment: notice: Sorry but the ideal would be CambridgeUS, as follows: \documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{color}

% %\usetheme{Madrid}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
% %gets rid of bottom navigation bars, then reset with {}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\textcolor{white}{\rule{\paperwidth}{5pt}}
}